# no device-tree blob file (dtb) is present

Tags: linux-kernel, device-tree

Can not figure out, why there is no dtb file under `arch/arm/boot/dts/`

- `dtc -O dtb -O test.dtb test.dts` debian device tree compiler works
- `scripts/dtc/dtc -O dtb -O test.dtb test.dts` kernel device tree
  compiler works too
- `make dtbs` runs without error, but there is no dtb file present

The output is as follows:

```
user1@vm:~/linux$ make dtbs
  CHK     include/config/kernel.release
  CHK     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
  CHK     include/generated/bounds.h
  CHK     include/generated/timeconst.h
  CHK     include/generated/asm-offsets.h
  CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
  CHK     scripts/mod/devicetable-offsets.h
```

I am missing an output like:

```
DTC     arch/arm/boot/dts/test.dtb
```

Kernel 4.14, armv7, target: sc573x-ezkit.

Any guesses?

Comment: Take a look at the rule specified under target `dtbs:` in `Makefile`. Maybe the actual recipe is missing!

Comment: Thank you so much.. the problem was a missing CONFIG_MACH_XX flag.